# Integrating factors and integrability of an ODE system

Tags: differential-equations, terminology

The following argument is from a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3402.pdf) about the [Bendixson-Dulac Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem).

> Consider a smooth differential equation on the plane
>   $$
> x'=g(x,y),\quad y'=h(x,y).
> $$
>   Suppose there exists a function $D(x,y)$ such that
>   $$
> (Dg)_x+(Dh)_y=0. 
> $$ 
>   *Then $D$ is an integrating factor and the system is integrable.*

A quick search for "integrable system" on Google returns results not satisfying.

Could anyone explain what the last sentence in the argument above means?

---

In the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3402.pdf) quoted above,

$$
g(x,y)=ax+bx^2+cxy,\quad h(x,y)=dy+exy+fy^2
$$

and $D(x,y)=x^ry^s$ for some $r,s$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X=g\partial_x + h\partial_y$ is the vector field whose flow lines are wanted. 

$\omega=hdx - gdy$ is a 1-form with kernel the span of $X$. 

Also $D\omega$ has kernel the span of $X$ for any function $D$ which does not vanish anywhere. If $d(D\omega)=0$ (this is your condition) then $D\omega$ is a closed 1-form, thus exact on simply connected sets. So $D\omega = dF$ for a function $F$ which can easily be computed by line integrals.
Thus the wanted flow lines are contained in the level sets of $F$. 

Finally,
the time dependence of the flow has to be computed extra.